# Remove Current/last Row From Datagridviewrows in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to remove the current row from datagridview which is not bound to any datasource and AllowUserToAddRows property is False.

I add rows to datagridview using the code

```
  Purchases.Rows.Add(selectedrow.Cells(0).Value, selectedrow.Cells(1).Value, selectedrow.Cells(2).Value, selectedrow.Cells(6).Value, "", "", selectedrow.Cells(3).Value
```

And i use this code to remove current row

```
  Private Sub Purchases_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Purchases.CellEndEdit
    Try
        If CDbl(Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells("Column7").Value) - CDbl(Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value) < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity entered is more than total in Stock " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value & " Has " & stock & " in Stock" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Increase Stock Level or Reduce Quantity Entered or See System Administrator for Help", "Pharm App " & Today.Year & "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Purchases.Rows.Remove(Purchases.CurrentRow)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

but i get an error saying

"Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to SetCurrentCellAddressCore function"

I tried to remove the last row with

```
   Purchases.Rows.RemoveAt(Purchases.RowCount - 1)
```

and i get the same error.

Please help as i am a newbie.

Comment: I do not get that error when I use `Purchases.Rows.Remove(Purchases.CurrentRow)`. It seems to work for me. What is `selectedrow` set to, before you add the row? I don't understand your add row line.

Comment: That error message suggests that the code is in an event handler where executing it would cause that same event handler to keep being invoked over and over.  The code is fine but your placement of it is wrong.  As you haven't told us where it is or under what circumstances you want to remove this row, we can't really help any further.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've edited the code and added the event and the circumstance i want to remove the row.

Comment: It seems bizarre to me that you would want to remove the current row because the user entered a value that was too big. Surely you'd give them the option to change the value.

Comment: Also, while `If CDbl(Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells("Column7").Value) - CDbl(Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value) < 0 Then` is not specifically wrong, it would be better to use `If CDbl(Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value) > CDbl(Purchases.CurrentRow.Cells("Column7").Value) Then`.  Even better would be to assign those two values to variables with meaningful names and then compare those variables.  What those cells contain is a complete mystery based on that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to remove the row *after* the CellEndEdit event, so replace this line:

```
Purchases.Rows.Remove(Purchases.CurrentRow)
```

with this:

```
Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() Purchases.Rows.Remove(Purchases.CurrentRow)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works with me

```
DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
```

Comment: The post mentioned they already have that property.  Your answer doesn't solve anything.